# How can I hide (make invisible) a single plotted point in GNU Octave?

Tags: plot, octave, invisible

I use the following function ([drawellipse.m](https://code.google.com/p/recognition-faces/source/browse/elipse/drawelipse.m)). I want to be able to draw the ellipse, but suppress/hide/make invisible the last point in the matrix (rx,ry)

Comment: You should add a simple, executable code snippet. Your linked code can't be run directly (error in naming drawellip vs drawellipse, missing solveelipse) and we don't know which parameter you are using for your function call. Basically you can modify the datapoint as shown in my answer and you may adapt it to work on the line you want. Or of course the easiest solution: edit drawelipse.m

Answer (score 0):

```
# simulate your drawellipse
plot(1:5, "-ro")
# get handle of line object
h = findobj (gcf, "type", "line")
# remove last point from xdata
set (h, "xdata", get(h, "xdata")(1:end-1))
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work for me. First I tried drawellip(Q,X,Y)
# get handle of line object
h = findobj (gcf, "type", "line")
# remove last point from xdata
set (h, "xdata", get(h, "xdata")(1:end-1))
And then various tweaks, but still no luck. Rod.